# Name "sb" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am just getting started with C# and and experimenting with a socket server to receive some data from client application.

**This is the string that is being received from the client application:**

> Value0_Value1_Value2

**Received data keep on appending to the previously received string like this**

> Value0_Value1_Value2
> Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2
> Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2
> Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2Value0_Value1_Value2

so i am trying to clear the StringBuilder, once the data is received from the client but i receive an **error** saying:

> The Name 'sb' does not exist in the current context

**This is the Code that is receiving the data from client :**

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
 
    String content = String.Empty;
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {

        string proce0, proce1, proce2, proce3, proce4, proce5 = String.Empty;
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
         
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(content);

        string[] Splitdata1 = content.Split('_');
        int splitelements = Splitdata1.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(splitelements);
        if (splitelements == 3)
        {
            proce0 = Splitdata1[0];
            proce1 = Splitdata1[1];
            proce2 = Splitdata1[2];
            Console.WriteLine("Values:\n" + proce0 + "\n" + proce1 + "\n" + proce2 + "\n" + "\n" + "\n");
            sb.Clear();
        }
        if (content.IndexOf("END5") > -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            Send(handler, content);
            sb.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        }
    }
}
```

***StateObject Class containing the string builder :***

```
public class StateObject

{
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public Socket workSocket = null;
}
```

what would be the correct way to clear the StringBuilder so that the string dont get appended to the previously received strings ?
or if there any other way to get rid of the string appending ?

Comment: In the inner ifs, you're trying to use `sb` directly instead of `state.sb`.

Comment: Double-clicking on the error message will bring you to the offending line of code. You have `sb.Clear()` in two places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sb` variable is not defined in entire `ReadCallback()` method. It is available as a property of `StateObject` class. You need to clear `sb` present in `StateObject` class like,

```
state.sb.Clear();
```

Your code looks like,

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ...
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        //****You have already done it over here****
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        if (splitelements == 3)
        {  
            ...
            state.sb.Clear();  //Change sb.Clear() to state.sb.Clear()
        }
        if (content.IndexOf("END5") > -1)
        { 
            ...
            state.sb.Clear();  //Change sb.Clear() to state.sb.Clear()
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer , i tried state.sb.Clear(); but even tho the errors are gone but still same appending issue

Comment: @Umer are you able to clear the string builder instance? or still facing appending issue?

Comment: i am  a bit confused because by the looks of it its clearing the string builder instance , but in some cases it does not clear the string builder , i mean for the first few times it prints single string that is received and all of a sudden it gives the appended string and then it goes back to normal

Comment: @umer, it will definitely clear StringBuilder instance. Check the scenario where it is failing and dubug it. Let me know if you need any help from my end

Comment: @ Prasad Telkikar you are right its actually working correctly , after spending some time tracing everything i found out there was a console.writeLine()   statement which was making printing the appended string for some reason